# Are their any software exist who can store or saved system audio?

Tags: windows, audio

i have a idea that i want to store audio of what i play in my system. like i listen some audio and want to store them as audio in my system are their any software exist to store them.

my means to store audio using a software then they can store audio what i play in my system. example youtube , vimeo video i play and software store audio for them. sometime when  i am unable to store them in my system. i can store their audio shadow.

Are their any software exist

Comment: Off-topic. Voting to move to [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: no user want this kind of software prehaps programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Total Recorder](http://www.totalrecorder.com/)

> Capture any sound played by a computer (including streaming audio, Internet telephony, and PC games), and use the included time shift-feature for off-hours recording.